# Use sys.stdin.readlines() to create an array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, sys

I want to create an array out of an input so I use sys.stdin.readlines(). My inputs are multiple integers looking like this:

```
random number
random number
random number 
random number
```

However sys.stdin.readlines() creates an array and turns all these random numbers into strings. The array looks like this:

```
Array = ['random number\n','random number\n','random number\n','random number\n']
```

That is not what I want. I want the input to be turnt into an array but I still want the array entries to be integers.

I use python so the arrays I am talking about are actually lists.

Comment: I do not really know. I see something I have not learned yet (raw_input) so by just looking at the other post no it would not help me fully. However somebody with more domain knowledge might see that differently.

Comment: well `raw_input` is simply a Python 2 function which is replaced with `input` in Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to convert them into integers using a comprehension or something similar e.g. `[int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readlines()]`